# Error: java.lang.NullPointerException occurs on workserver when running Process Instance in dolphinscheduler

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

Using Standalone deployment to deploy the dolphinscheduler successfully. Follow the totorial video(https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1d64y1s7eZ), when I try running Process Instance in dolphinscheduler, some errors happened on the workerserver and ApiApplicationserver.
[workerserver Error picture]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWQsU.png

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.worker.processor.TaskExecuteProcessor.getTaskLogPath(TaskExecuteProcessor.java:129) ~[dolphinscheduler-server-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.worker.processor.TaskExecuteProcessor.buildAckCommand(TaskExecuteProcessor.java:152) ~[dolphinscheduler-server-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.worker.processor.TaskExecuteProcessor.doAck(TaskExecuteProcessor.java:117) ~[dolphinscheduler-server-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.worker.processor.TaskExecuteProcessor.process(TaskExecuteProcessor.java:108) ~[dolphinscheduler-server-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.remote.handler.NettyServerHandler$1.run(NettyServerHandler.java:118) ~[dolphinscheduler-remote-1.3.0.jar:1.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_311]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_311]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_311]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_311]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_311]
```

[ApiApplicationserver Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkbau.png)

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : xxx.xxx.com:25
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.utils.MailUtils.getStringObjectMap(MailUtils.java:309)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.utils.MailUtils.sendMails(MailUtils.java:124)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.manager.EmailManager.send(EmailManager.java:39)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.plugin.EmailAlertPlugin.process(EmailAlertPlugin.java:96)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.runner.AlertSender.run(AlertSender.java:84)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.AlertServer.start(AlertServer.java:82)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.alert.AlertServer.main(AlertServer.java:89)
    
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:965)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:876)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:780)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
        at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1459)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your email alert configuration, it seems that the alert parameter is wrong and the authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just run simple echo with shell, maybe your environment does not config correct, you can follow the official doc to install [doc](https://dolphinscheduler.apache.org/zh-cn/docs/1.3.1/user_doc/quick-start.html)